# vue dom doesn't re-render

Tags: vue.js, v-for, rerender

I use v-for to render table rows

```html
<table>
  <tr v-for="(item, i) in data">
    <td>
      <button v-if="...">....</button>
      <el-tooltipplacement="right">
        <button v-if="..." >...</button>
        <div slot="content">
          <button @click="...">...</button>
          <button @click="...">...</button>
        </div>
      </el-tooltip>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The tooltip is a component of element ui,
the tooltip will display after hovering the button.
The table data is gotten by ajax call,
and there are several pages,
it will get the data by ajax call while turning page,
the problem occurs after turning page.
Some tooltip will not display after hovering,
I assumed the problem is doms don't re-render,
I used $forceUpdate() after ajax call,
but it had no effect.
If you can please help me out.

element ui Tooltip component and exmaple： https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/tooltip

Comment: When people have problems with their code, we need all the code required to reproduce the problem (and nothing more). We call that a [mcve]. You currently only included (part) of your template, but we do require the relevant script parts of the component itself too. Please find out which parts of your component you need to keep to still be able to reproduce the problem, and edit your question to add in the relevant parts.

Comment: please share code for `Tooltip`  component or live demo if possible ?

Comment: I would like to apologize for lack of consideration.
I have filled up the component and examples.

Comment: Element UI Docs uses <el-tooltip> and you are using <Tooltip>...

Comment: The problem is your data is not reactive. You need to make it reactive.